# How to parse CLOB datatype to get Value

Tags: xml, extract

I have the following XML stored in Database as CLOB and I would like to `SELECT` the value of hiPolicyYear tag from the data given below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<boForm>
  <boField>
    <name>hiLeaveTypeDesc_1</name>
    <value>Annual Leave</value>
  </boField>
  <boField>
    <name>dpStartDate_1</name>
    <value>20180108 000000</value>
  </boField>
  <boField>
    <name>dpEndDate_1</name>
    <value>20180121 000000</value>
  </boField>
  <boField>
    <name>hiPolicyYear</name>
    <value>2018</value>
  </boField>
</boForm>
```

I have tried the following sql:

```
SELECT --XMLTYPE(BUSOBJ_XML)
  .extract('//boField//value//text()')
  .getStringVal() 
  XMLTYPE(BUSOBJ_XML)
  .extract('//boField//value//text()')
  .getStringVal()
FROM business_object where busobj_id in ( 6854135, 6419639);
```

But gives me all the values from the XML in the value field, I even tried adding the where clause like this:

```
SELECT XMLTYPE(BUSOBJ_XML)
  .extract('//boField//value//text()')
  .getStringVal()
```

But this give null FROM business_object where busobj_id in ( 6854135, 6419639) 
and XMLTYPE(BUSOBJ_XML).extract('//boField//name//text()').getStringVal() = 'hiPolicyYear';

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: SELECT --XMLTYPE(BUSOBJ_XML).extract('//boField//value//text()').getStringVal()
XMLTYPE(BUSOBJ_XML).extract('//boField//value//text()').getStringVal()
 FROM   business_object where  busobj_id in ( 6854135, 6419639);

Comment: But gives me all the values from the XML in the value field, I even tried adding the where clause like this:SELECT 
XMLTYPE(BUSOBJ_XML).extract('//boField//value//text()').getStringVal()  but this give null
 FROM   business_object where  busobj_id in ( 6854135, 6419639)
and   XMLTYPE(BUSOBJ_XML).extract('//boField//name//text()').getStringVal() = 'hiPolicyYear';

Comment: Please include this information in your question directly

Comment: Added extra sql statements from comments into the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answers :

select himastart , busobj_id from (select extractValue(xmltype(busobj_xml), '/boForm/boField[name="hiMAStart"]/value') as himastart , busobj_id
from business_object where busobj_id in ( 6854135,6419639)) where himastart is not null;